# Uploading file via HttpURLConnection do not do it completely

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I have a code.
Frontend:

```
public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {

    String fileName = sourceFileUri;
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    DataOutputStream dos;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

        dialog.dismiss();
        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"
                +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"
                        +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);
            }
        });

        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        try {
            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
            // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=uploaded_file;filename=" + fileName + " + lineEnd");
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            // create a buffer of  maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
            // send multipart form data necessary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                    + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n "
                                +uploadFileName;

                        messageText.setText(msg);
                        Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "File Upload Complete.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            //close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            ex.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                    Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "MalformedURLException",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            e.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                    Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            Log.e("Upload file Exception", "Exception : "
                    + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
        return serverResponseCode;

    } // End else block
}
```

Backend:

```
$file_path = "uploads/files/";

$file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path))
{
echo "success";
}else{
echo "fail";
}
```

This code works, but:

1. I can't upload small files (10-1000 bytes), there is no errors in server response, but I don't see any small files
2. Big files changes, for example I send 3925 bytes size file to server, but server saves only 1002 bytes (end of the file). 26216 bytes -> 26173 etc.
   Can you help me what a reason of such strange error, or maybe you have an idea how to fix it?
   Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
Looks like I've solved the problem. There is a new code, works fine. Key solution - to use `System.lineSeparator()` instead `String lineEnd = "\r\n";`:

```
public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {

    String fileName = sourceFileUri;
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    DataOutputStream dos;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    //String boundary = "*****file_Antares*****";
    String boundary = "WebKitFormBoundary7$G67whGfe341h6@fr561";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 8*1024;

    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

        dialog.dismiss();
        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"
                +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"
                        +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);
            }
        });

        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        try {
            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
            // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
            conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);
            conn.connect(); //new!!!
            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + System.lineSeparator());// add new System.lineSeparator()) 
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=uploaded_file;filename=" + fileName + System.lineSeparator());
            dos.writeBytes(System.lineSeparator());

            // create a buffer of  maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            
            while ((bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            // send multipart form data necessary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(System.lineSeparator());
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + System.lineSeparator());
            //close the streams //
            dos.close();
            dos.flush();
            fileInputStream.close();
            
            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                    + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                +uploadFileName;
                        messageText.setText(msg);
                        Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "File Upload Complete.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            ex.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                    Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "MalformedURLException",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            e.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                    Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            Log.e("Upload file Exception", "Exception : "
                    + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
        return serverResponseCode;

    } // End else block
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But with while (bytesRead >= 0) this code looping and never stops.

Comment: i've updated your question to make use of android, instead of android studio, because you're not really asking about the IDE. it's important to use the right tags, otherwise people won't see your question. generally, use android, if you're asking about the IDE specifically, use android-studio

Comment: Are you aware that if the boundary `*****` is contained in your file data then this code will fail.

Comment: Yes, I know, and I have a problem even on TXT files with no *****

Answer (score 0):

You call `conn.getResponseCode();` too early.

Doing so ends the request, but your code to flush and close `dos` will be executed a lot later:

```
dos.flush(); // can be omitted as close is called directly afterwards
dos.close();
```

Move this code block before `conn.getResponseCode();`.

Additionally your while loop is defect because you always write `buferSize` instead of `bytesRead` bytes to `dos`. Also the whole calculations about buffer size is totally unnecessary. Just use a fixed size buffer instead, that will always work.

```
        buffer = new byte[8192];

        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer);
        while (bytesRead >= 0) {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer);
        }
```

Or shorter:

```
        buffer = new byte[8192];
        while ((bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
        dos.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, I really appreciate. I've changed code, but no result. :( I've send 3925 bytes size file, and still get 1002 bytes file on server. I even see correct buffer size in debugger in 'bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer);', but I still have the same problem, I have no idea why.

Comment: @AlexDem May be your server code is defect as well?

Comment: Probably not, I have this PHP server with this code for uploading files from HTML + JavaScript and it works fine.

Comment: @AlexDem If you can access your server via HTTP do so and record the upload via Wireshark/tshark to see what is actually uploaded. Compare it with an upload of a different client (e.g. via web site). That is the best way to identify where the problem is (client or server side).

Comment: I identified another problem. Please just use a fixed buffer size like 8K = 8192. `available()` method is optional in Java.